# Create new unique session ID from timedelta-values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that includes a specific session-IDs for customer clicks on a website and the timedifference between the actual click and the next click in the DataFrame. Meaning, delta_t in row 1 is the timedifference between row 1 and row 2. The timedifference is calculated from a servertime.

Now i want to create a new session_ID based on these informations. Meaning, if the difference between two clicks exceeds a certain level (for example > 1 days 00:00:00.00), then they should considered as different sessions.

My df looks like the following:

```
session                 delta_t      
      1     11 days 18:59:13.23
      1      1 days 02:22:13.23
      1      0 days 18:59:13.23
      7      1 days 18:59:13.23
      7      0 days 07:59:13.23
      7      0 days 04:59:13.23
      7      2 days 18:59:13.23
```

The new variable should also take 'session' into account, so even though the delta_t is below the defined time-level, if the next session is different from the previous, then they should still be considered different.

My df should look like the following, with a threshold on "1 days 00:00:00.00".

```
session                 delta_t        new_session
      1     11 days 18:59:13.23                  1
      1      1 days 02:22:13.23                  2
      1      0 days 18:59:13.23                  3
      7      1 days 18:59:13.23                  4
      7      0 days 07:59:13.23                  5
      7      0 days 04:59:13.23                  5
      7      2 days 18:59:13.23                  5
      7      1 days 18:59:13.23                  6
```

I hope it makes sense, otherwise just ask. I am using pandas in Python.

/Nicolai

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. `The new variable should also take 'session' into account, so even though the delta_t is below the defined time-level, if the next session is different from the previous, then they should still be considered different.`

Comment: Can you explain `3` number from output in row `1      0 days 18:59:13.23                  3` ?

Comment: Sorry if I have been unclear. Delta_t is the timedifference between the acutal row and the next row in the df. Therefore if delta_t is below the threshold (1 days), the row and the next row should have the same new_session number. Also, when session is different, the new_session should always be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

Firstly look for the entries that have a date diffrerence smaller than the established threshold of 1 day:

```
cond1 = ~(df.delta_t.shift(1).abs() < pd.to_timedelta('1 day'))
```

Look for the indices at which the `session` id changes:

```
cond2 = df.session.diff().fillna(0).ne(0).shift(-1)
```

Apply [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) after having checked if one of the two conditions is satisfied, i.e. even though the the time difference is not smaller than 1 day, the `new_session` id should increase if the `session` id is different:

```
df['new_session'] = (cond1|cond2).astype(int).cumsum()
print(df)

     delta_t                  session    new_session
0 11 days 18:59:13.230000        1            1
1  1 days 02:22:13.230000        1            2
2  0 days 18:59:13.230000        1            3
3  1 days 18:59:13.230000        7            4
4  0 days 07:59:13.230000        7            5
5  0 days 04:59:13.230000        7            5
6  2 days 18:59:13.230000        7            6
```

Comment: This is a brilliant way to do it. It's not completely right since you should'nt calculate the difference (delta_t) because it is already the time difference. So cond1 should be: "cond1 = ~(df.delta_t.shift(1).abs() < pd.to_timedelta('1 day'))".
But thank you a lot for the solution :)

Comment: Yes, True! I was working thinking they were dates for some reason. Glad it helped anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would find number of days in the `delta_t` column and then create a 0/1 column, which represent change of session.

After that, `new_session` is just the cumulative summation of the `change_f_sess`

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'session':[1,1,1,7],'delta_t':['11 days 18:59:13.23','1 days 02:22:13.23','0 days 18:59:13.23','1 days 18:59:13.23']})

df['days']=df.apply(lambda row: row.delta_t[:row.delta_t.find('d')] , axis = 1).astype(int)
df['days'] = df['days'].shift(1)
df.loc[0,'days'] = 1
df['change_f_sess']=df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row.days > 0 else 0 , axis = 1).astype(int)

df['new_session'] = df['change_f_sess'].cumsum()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
               delta_t  session  days  change_f_sess  new_session
0  11 days 18:59:13.23        1   1.0              1            1
1   1 days 02:22:13.23        1  11.0              1            2
2   0 days 18:59:13.23        1   1.0              1            3
3   1 days 18:59:13.23        7   0.0              0            3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

But this does not exactly fix it. The delta_t column is the difference between the acutal row and the next row - which means than in your df, row 1 and 2 should not have similar new_session IDs.

Also, this is quite inefficient, my df consists of 35 million rows, and my memory is filled by the first statement (with 16GB RAM).

Comment: " which means than in your df, row 1 and 2 should not be similar" can you explain this part?

Comment: In the output, row 1 and row 2 are not similar!

Comment: They have different new_session IDs

Comment: The time difference between row 1 and 2 is delta_t from row 1. The time difference between row 2 and 3 is delta_t from row 2 and so on.

Comment: And when i refer to row 1 and 2, i am refering to the indexes

Comment: updated the code according to your calculation of delta_t